# How to derive a new class from DataTemplate and then use it in place of DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

How do I derive a new class from DataTemplate and then use it in place of DataTemplate?

For example, in C#:

```
public class DerivedDataTemplate : DataTemplate
{
}
```

Then in XAML:

```
<local: DerivedDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeType}">
    <Grid>
        ... UI here ...
    </Grid>
</local:DerivedDataTemplate>
```

When I try to use my derived data template class the follow exception is generated:

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
Message="'Grid' object cannot be added to 'DerivedDataTemplate'. Object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory'.

Does anyone know how to work around this exception and successfully use a class derived from DataTemplate?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you inheriting from DataTemplate?

Comment: I basically wanted to be able to have a special kind of data template that I could attach extra data to and use the built in rules for resource search and template instantiation.  I ended up doing it a different way - but it would have been simpler to inherit from DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me (although I did not create a local type).  I copied your code and had to remove the space between local: and DerivedDataTemplate in the XAML declaration. In Blend 3 it wouldn't even run for me, I'm not sure about Blend 2.

Comment: The space was just a typo when putting it on SO, my real code didn't have that error. So when you say it worked for you what exactly do you mean?  In the next sentence you seem to say that it didn't work for you!?  I am using Visual Studio 2008 Express.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear: your code worked for me without the space. *with* the space it would not even run in Blend 3.